# Integration of Hyperledger Composer with Hyperledger Explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

My question is related to integration of Hyperledger Composer with Hyperledger Explorer.

I am able to see channel specific explorer dashboard but not abIe to see chaincode, assets, participants or transactions added using rest server.

Is explorer works with application set up using node sdk or cli only ?

And due to this only Historian added in Composer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever manage to connect a Composer Business Network with Explorer?

Answer (score 3):

the Blockchain or - Fabric Explorer  - has views/dashboard specifically for Hyperledger Fabric, and is Fabric specific. Composer provides views of the business network (or the chaincode deployed as a business network).

So 'exploration' of Fabric blockchain elements (relating to Blocks and Fabric transactions) is separate to the Composer business network elements you see through using the Composer REST APIs (ie related to a specify Composer business network you deployed - and for which you have views of individual assets, participants and transactions - as well as a history of transactions - that got you to the current world state). So the former is a Fabric view - and the latter is a view into a specific part of the ledger - ie the business network in question.

Comment: Agree with you Paul. Use of explorer to view transactions , chain code or blocks store on ledger. With the use of composer also transactions are getting stored on ledger on blockchain network.So ideally we should be able to those details on explorer. Please confirm whether my understanding is correct or not.